# Java: Cannot instantiate the type Foo

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my own version of `HashMap` with some utility methods.

**Foo.java**:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Foo<String, Parameter> extends HashMap<String, Parameter> {

    public Foo() {
      super();
    }

    public Parameter Add(String key, MyType type) {
        return put(key, new Parameter(type)); // -> This line causes compilation error
    }
  }
```

The following line:

```
new Parameter(type);
```

produces `Cannot instantiate the type Foo`.

I checked **`Parameter` class and it is not an abstract class/interface**, why am I getting this error?

**EDIT**
Changing class declaration as following solved the problem:

```
public class Foo extends HashMap<String, Parameter> {
```

Comment: What is the type of `MyType`?

Comment: Can you post the code of Parameter class? at least the constructors? I'm missing why instantiating Parameter fails on Foo.

Comment: The problem is solved. See the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an abstract class - it's a type parameter at the moment, as is `String`! Your class is generic, with two type parameters. I believe you meant:

```
public class Foo extends HashMap<String, Parameter> {
```

Now it's a non-generic class.

Answer (score 3):

Your class declaration should be

```
public class Foo extends HashMap<String, Parameter> {
```

But it's almost always a bad idea to extend a `HashMap`. You should *use* a `Map` instance inside your class instead. Also, methods should always start with a lower-case letter in Java.